# Fft size from wav file - Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, fft, wav, spectrum

I'm trying to perform a spectrum analysis of a wav file in matlab, but I have few knowledge of digital signal processing.

I'm having issues to get de right level in dB from the fft function and couldn't find a proper answer from previous posts

Here is my code for now :

```
% spectre from wav

clear all
close all

[sig, fs]=audioread('BKSinus1000Hz.wav')
S=1.51; %sensitivity of microphone  mV/Pa
sig1=1.51*sig(:,1);

N=length(sig1);
t=linspace(0,N/fs,N);
figure(101)
plot(t,sig1)

Nfft=1024;
f=linspace(0,fs,Nfft);

A1=abs(fft(sig1,Nfft));
figure(102)
axes('units','centimeters','position',[1. 1. 18. 12.]);
hold on; box on;
set(gca,'xlim',[0 1*1E4])
semilogx(f(1:Nfft/2),20*log10(A1(1:Nfft/2)/(2E-5)))

sig2=sig1.*hanning(N);
figure(201)
plot(t,sig2)

A2=abs(fft(sig2,Nfft));
figure(202)
axes('units','centimeters','position',[1. 1. 18. 12.]);
hold on; box on;
set(gca,'xlim',[100 1*1E4],'xtick',[800 2E3 1E4])
semilogx(f(1:Nfft/2),20*log10(A2(1:Nfft/2)/(2E-5)))
```

I trie to use a Hanning window, bu i think i'm having issues with the size of the fft: matlab appear to use only the Nfft-First samples of the wav file (and not the whole file)  to calculate fft, so levels are wrong.

So i've two questions : what are the rules to choose a proper size of fft (not knowing the frequency content of the file). And how to convert wav samples values into dB ?

Comment: Do you want a dB level that tells you a proper relative dB level (comparison with different peaks in your file) or do you want a dB level that tells you the actual 'sound pressure' of what you recorded? In the second case, what exactly do you want to determine? The sound pressure at the source, if so, you should take into account the distance between the microphone and the source as well. (I'm afraid I don't know the answer to your problem, but these questions came to mind and might help others)

Comment: Also, have a look at this link for getting a proper size fft.: http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/250288-fft-scaling-of-audio-freq

Comment: I want a level in dB that tells the actual sound pressure at the microphone (not at the source). (I know exactly this level where the microphone is, but i want to check it in matlab, but i dont' know the conversion from wav file values to Pa, mV or dB....

Comment: I'd say you have to scale the fft with one over the length of the fft (Nfft). This is definitely necessary.  In my code (not for sound, but it's probably the same) it looks like this `abs(fft(sig1,[],1)/Nfft);. In my case, the transimpedance of the detector is taken into account (does the sensitivity of the microphone include losses in the sound-card?). Furthermore, check out this: http://nl.mathworks.com/help/daq/examples/acquire-and-analyze-sound-pressure-data-from-an-iepe-microphone.html .

Comment: I still don't have the correct values (not from losses in sound card since there is almost a 50 dB error). But you were right !  i forgot to scale the amplitude of fft by Nfft. This is a first step. 
I might have some problems with the definition of dB for sound (dBSPL) but i dont know where is my mistake (pressure reference, RMS value from microphone...)

Comment: If your microphone gives an RMS output, you'll have to square to get to intensity. In my code, I square after the fft to accomplish this. However, I think that squaring before should do the same. (So you'd just have to square A1)

Comment: My bad, i wasn't clear : my microphone doesn't have an RMS output. it's mV corresponding to pressure variation (so it gives the max). 

In fact, i just need to know : when i have a signal (lets say sinus) of 1 mV amplitude, to what amplitude does it correspond when saving it in wav format...
I can see a difference between the values in mv and the values of sig1 when imported in matlab, but i've no way of knowing accurately the relation

Comment: You need to add the sensitivity of the microphone (v/uPa). Also you should consider using `pwelch` instead.